# Retrieve data from same partitions across multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In our current system we have 4 topics

> Topic1(20),Topic2(20),Topic3(20),Topic4(20)

For producer side we have applied custom IDpartitioner which bacisally do ID%20 (20=numpartition)

```
public Integer partition(String topic, Object key, Object value, int numPartition) {
            try {
                log.info("topic:{} key:{} numPartition:{}", topic, key.toString(), numPartition);
                int currPartition = Integer.valueOf((String) key) % numPartition;
                if(currPartition < 0) {
                    log.info("Partition less than 0 for topic:{} key:{} currPartition:{} ", topic, key.toString(), currPartition);
                    currPartition = 1;
                }
                return currPartition;
            } catch(Exception e) {
               return 1;
            }
        }
```

For consumer side We have **2 consumers** in our consumer group **cloud-consumer** on ECS cluster.
with below configs. Each consumer is listening to all 4 topics.

```
  @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RangeAssignor.class.getName());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

Now the problem is we are not receiving all messages with same partition on same consumer from different topics.

Tried checking partition assignment also below is the result

```
ConsumerRebalanceListener myConsumerRebalanceListener(){onPartitionsAssigned()}
```

> Consumer 1 > Topic 1- (0-9) ,Topic 2-(0-9) ,Topic 3- (10-19) ,Topic 4-> (10-19) 
> Consumer 2> Topic 1- (10-19) ,Topic 2-(10-19) ,Topic 3-> (0-9) ,Topic 4- (0-9)

Now as you can see for **Partition 5** we received data on both consumers from topic1 and topic3

Comment: What is your question exactly? It feels like you're expecting each consumer to get the same IDs for each of the topics? That's not how partitions works.

Comment: I just want same Id should come on same consumer from all topics . Is it even possible ?

Comment: Rethink your design, may be use a database to aggregate the events with same IDs after consuming from topic and try to achieve the requirement, rather than doing something which is not meant for Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

It's working as expected. There's no overlapping partitions being consumed within the same consumer group. You cannot have both consumer 1 and 2 both reading "partition 5" of the same topic, if they are in the same group.

Partition assignment will not be consistent across multiple topics unless you manually assign them to the consumers. Consumers have no knowledge of your producer's partitioning scheme, and ideally shouldn't.

You will have per-message ordering within each partition, though, and each deployed consumer should only care about that, rather than reading specific keys from specific partitions; this will help you scale better and handle consumer group rebalances

As mentioned in the comments, perhaps you can use Kafka Streams instead and perform a groupByKey operation to shuffle the data across your consumer instances

Comment: I was wondering though, if you do Kafka Streams KTable joins, they refer to objects with the same key as well; to be able to do that, a specific consumer does need to receive the same keys across topics. Doesn't that mean Streams needs to have a repartitioner like that?

Comment: @dani Kafka Streams does do repartitioning, when necessary, but I think the partition assignment is still non deterministic